# Macro for pgfplots/gnuplot exponential regression line

Tags: pgfplots, macros, gnuplot, csv

I am trying to create a series of plots with exponential regression that are automatically generated from comma/tab separated `.csv` files and `pgfplots` with help from `gnuplot`. When not using macros I achieve the desired result.

(Note: if you want to test it yourself, you need to have `gnuplot` installed and use the `-shell-escape` command line parameter when compiling. Tested on `pdflatex`/`xelatex`/`lualatex`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
x,  y
2,  0.000058
3,  0.001888
4,  0.058763
5,  1.78986
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    grid=major,
    ylabel=x,
    xlabel=y,
    ymin=-0.5, ymax=2.5, xmin=1.5, xmax=5.5
]
\addplot [raw gnuplot, color=red, no marks, smooth] gnuplot {
    f(x)=a*(b^(c*x));
    a=7e-8;
    b=2.7;
    c=3.4;
    fit f(x) 'data.csv' using 1:2 via a,b,c;
    plot [x=1.5:5.5] f(x);
};
\addplot [color=black, mark=*, only marks] table [col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{sample caption text}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which yields this:

[image]

I want to get the same result using macros, but the following doesn’t work. I replace y/x labels, y/x min/max values, data file path and caption like this (code is essentially the same as previous example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
x,  y
2,  0.000058
3,  0.001888
4,  0.058763
5,  1.78986
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\expchart}[8]{ % ylabel, xlabel, ymin, ymax, xmin, xmax, csvPath,   caption
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        grid=major,
        ylabel={#1},
        xlabel={#2},
        ymin={#3}, ymax={#4}, xmin={#5}, xmax={#6}
        ]
    \addplot [raw gnuplot, color=red, no marks, smooth] gnuplot {
        f(x)=a*(b^(c*x));
        a=7e-8;
        b=2.7;
        c=3.4;
        fit f(x) '{#7}' using 1:2 via a,b,c;
        plot [x={#5}:{#6}] f(x);
    };
    \addplot [color=black, mark=*, only marks] table [col sep=comma] {{#7}};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{{#8}}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
}

\expchart
{y}
{x}
{-0.5}
{2.5}
{1.5}
{5.5}
{data.csv}
{sample caption text}

\end{document}
```

which yields this:

[image]

And everything is the same but the exponential regression line. What causes this? Is it maybe related to `gnuplot` being an external program and as such having trouble dealing with variables in macros? Am I maybe on the entirely wrong track using `gnuplot`? Should I be using something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gnuplot does not like literal `{` and `}` characters in it's input (they are reserved for complex numbers).

So remove the `{}` pairs around the macro parameters in the gnuplot input (the `\addplot[...] gnuplot{...};` lines) and it should work.

(Tested with gnuplot 5.1 CVS snapshot version, self compiled)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
x,  y
2,  0.000058
3,  0.001888
4,  0.058763
5,  1.78986
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\expchart}[8]{ % ylabel, xlabel, ymin, ymax, xmin, xmax, csvPath,   caption
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
        grid=major,
        ylabel=#1,
        xlabel={#2},
        ymin={#3}, ymax={#4}, xmin={#5}, xmax={#6}
        ]
    \addplot [raw gnuplot, color=red, no marks, smooth] gnuplot {
        f(x)=a*(b^(c*x));
        a=7e-8; 
        b=2.7; 
        c=3.4; 
        fit f(x) '#7' using 1:2 via a,b,c; 
        plot [x=#5:#6] f(x); 
    };
    \addplot [color=black, mark=*, only marks] table [col sep=comma] {#7};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{{#8}}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
}

\expchart
{y}
{x}
{-0.5}
{2.5}
{1.5}
{5.5}
{data.csv}
{sample caption text}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, friend! It worked for me on gnuplot 5.0.0 (from MacPorts) as well.

Comment: @svenper: Well, it should work even for very old versions of gnuplot, since there is no feature added only recently.